# Show deployed application versions in Environments tab

Tags: azure-devops

I have a deployment pipeline in azure-devops and it takes artifacts from other pipelines and deploy it to different environments. Yml looks like this:

```yaml
...
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - develop
            - release
            - master
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline-1
      source: different-repo-pipeline-1
    - pipeline: pipeline-2
      source: different-repo-pipeline-2

  ...
  jobs:
  - deployment: some-name
    environment: develop
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: pipeline-1
            - download: pipeline-2
            # Do real deployment
```

After deployment on target environment tab I saw:
[image: environment tab without some personal info]

There is no clue on it about deployed versions. I know this version inside deployment steps, or at least can use variables from pipelines (resources.pipeline.pipeline-1.runName). But I don't see any options to add this info to Environment deployment tab. Can it be done in some ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. We don't have any way to control what is displayed on environment tab.